# Duplicate assembly embedding

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, fody-costura

I'm experiencing the following issue with Costura, when using the <IncludeAssemblies> tag to provide the list of assemblies to embed, I get a duplicate. Specifically Jetbrains.Annotations assembly is duplicated. All other assemblies are only embedded once.

I can see both in the output of Costura, during build, and using DotPeek to inspect the resources of the generated target assembly.

Using the "default" mode of embedding does not trigger this issue. Unfortunately I cannot use the "default" mode since one of my assemblies is an Interop that fails to be included (using Embed Interop Types = false and Copy Local = true).

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you needn't embed Jetbrains.Annotations at all. It's not even used at runtime. The attributes contained in that assembly have a Conditional attribute on them which is only set while Resharper is inspecting your code.

You should be able to safely set `Copy Local = False` and remove Jetbrains.Annotations from your `FodyWeavers.xml` file.